# Mongoose unique combination of objectsId in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a chat application with Message and Conversation schemas.

In the conversation schema I want to store the participants (users) in an array but I want this array to be unique for each combination of users. For example, if there is a conversation with participants [John, Robert] I want to restrict to create another conversation with [John, Robert] or [Robert, John].

```
const ConversationSchema = new Schema({
   participants: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true }]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the application level. Make use of the [`$all` operator](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) and check if the participants array already exists or not. Something like this:

```js
// Assuming your mongoose model is named Conversation
const alreadyExists = await Conversation.exists({ particpants: { $all: [ "John" , "Robert" ] }});

// handle however you see fit
if (alreadyExists) throw new Error("Conversation already exists!");
```

Comment: Thank you, it is working. But is there a way to do it also in the schema for more security?